# SSRS calling Monthname inside switch

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that can be grouped monthly, quarterly, or annually. With my data, I have two columns, ActivationYear and ActivationMonthOrQuarter. I get ActivationMonthOrQuarter when I run the report, so I can have values ranging from 1-12 (1-12 if monthly, 1-4 if quarterly). If the grouping option is annually the ActivationMonthOrQuarter field will be null.

The issue I am running into is that it seems to still try and call the MONTHNAME function even when I use GroupingOption = "Annual" and throws an error since it cannot call it on a NULL value.

```
=SWITCH(
    Parameters!GroupingOption.Value = "Annual", "",
    Parameters!GroupingOption.Value = "Quarterly", "Q" & Fields!ActivationMonthOrQuarter.Value,
    Parameters!GroupingOption.Value = "Monthly", MONTHNAME(Fields!ActivationMonthOrQuarter.Value)
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=SWITCH(
    Parameters!GroupingOption.Value = "Annual", "",
    Parameters!GroupingOption.Value = "Quarterly", "Q" & Fields!ActivationMonthOrQuarter.Value,
    Parameters!GroupingOption.Value = "Monthly", MONTHNAME(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!ActivationMonthOrQuarter.Value),1,Fields!ActivationMonthOrQuarter.Value))
    )
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: It looks like I'm still getting the same error when doing the annual option. I'll keep looking into this. Is there a way for it to not call the MONTHNAME function? Isn't that what the SWITCH statement should be handling?

Comment: @ferensilver, just for testing try removing the Monthly option in the expression and select Annual option in the parameter. Does it work?

Comment: yes. If I remove the monthly option quarterly and annual work as intended.

Comment: @ferensilver, What is the error you get when using my expression? Could you paste it here?

Comment: It doesn't throw an error building it, it just shows something like this:https://i.imgur.com/g8AcM64.png. Is there a way to see what the actual #Error is? I am just assuming it's with MONTHNAME at this point.

Comment: @ferensilver, where are you using this expression? It seems you are using this expression in a textbox, is this textbox inside the scope of the group? Could you provide a sample data of your dataset to understand correctly what you are after? Also #Error generally throws warnings, see the Error List window.

Comment: It's inside a text box in a table that has a grouping. The table has the sum of payments grouped by the year and optionally the quarter or month I don't see any warnings.